# how to write a regular expression for this url?

Tags: regex

The initial Urls are: 
http://www.site.com/ad/a32-de21-ghi-30/99-134565.html
http://www.site.com/ad/a10-b20-c99/99-143.html
http://www.site.com/ad/1tb-bed-h442/99-6425.html

I want to keep the domain, the "ad" and the "99-"

I can't figure this out, and I come up with this Reg

```
http://www.site.com/ad/\w+/50-\d+\.html
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.`

Comment: So you want a rewrite rule that rewrites all these URLs to `site.com/ad/99-`? If not, please make your question more clear. What is the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://www\.site\.com/ad/[\w-]+/99-[0-9]+\.html` would work.

I find [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) to be a good page for regex testing.

Comment: For some reason, I'm unable to edit my answer to properly escape the URL dots as intended. Not absolutely necessary, but more correct.